# Windows 7 Update Failure 800B0100

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, service-pack

After updating to Windows 7 SP1 I updated with every new update that came out, but there were problems with the last two:

[image]

**UPDATE:** In the updates history I have found a lot of updates failed:

[image]

What can be done? Can I manually update?

P.S. I was offered a fix for this: **Windows6.1-KB947821-v12-x64**. Should I install?

Comment: Have you been try to download updates after restarting PC or not. Try and then give a reply hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: Restarted PC and updates are still failing.

Comment: The answers doesn't help you?......Strange....What settings you have for updates? "Let me choose which download and when to install them" setting I think you have set it to Install Updates automatically.

Comment: And of course you should take a try with that HOTFIX provided by Microsoft for windows update issue. As in my case when I used XP there were a problem with hibernation and then I found a HOTFIX for that and after installed it I never face that problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the dialog says: reboot Windows. Then check WindowsUpdate and try to install any remaining updates. If that keeps giving an error then you can try to manually install the updates.

Comment: How do i manually install updates?

Comment: I think you should have to change settings for windows updates to this way got to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Update\Change settings and set the 2nd option from drop down menu "Download Updates but let me choose whether to install them."

Comment: Look up the kb number on Microsoft's website and download the msu file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes run the  SUR tool [as instructed Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Windows-Update-error-800B0100)

> If you receive the Windows Update error 800b0100, it means that a file needed by Windows Update is not registered with Windows correctly. The System Update Readiness Tool can correct some conditions that cause this error. To use the tool, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to the [System Update Readiness Tool webpage](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=947821). In the Information for advanced users section, find the version of Windows and system type of your computer, and then click the link to download the System Update Readiness Tool. If you don't know which version of Windows you have, see [View your computer information](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/View-your-computer-information).
> 2. Run the tool
> 3. Run Windows Update again.
>
> Note:
>
> Typically, the scan takes 15 minutes or less, but it can take longer on some computers. The Windows Update progress bar is not updated during the scan, and progress seems to stop at 60% complete for some time. This behavior is expected. The scan is still running and you should not cancel the update.
>
> If the problem persists after you take these steps, go to the [Microsoft Update Solution Center website](http://support.microsoft.com/ph/6527) to find more information about the error code or to request support by e‑mail.
>
> Error codes this applies to:
>
> WindowsUpdate_800B0100
>
> 0x800B0100

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and every tutorial/hint I found did not work until I discovered the following blog post:

["How to fix Server Manager Errors after installing updates (HRESULT:0x800F0818 / HRESULT:0x800B0100)"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/roplatforms/2010/05/12/how-to-fix-server-manager-errors-after-installing-updates-hresult0x800f0818-hresult0x800b0100/)

This worked for several "windows 7 ultimate" clients, by using the following "simple" steps. Afterwards the problem was gone and updates worked again.

1. Run the "Microsoft Update Readiness Tool".
2. Check the "CheckSUR.log" (C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CheckSUR.log) which files cause problems and identify the KB number.
3. Download the update file from the internet (a ".msu"-file).
4. Extract the ".cab"-file from the ".msu"-file.
5. Inside the ".cab"-file look for the files from the "CheckSUR.log" and replace them in "C:\Windows\Servicing\Packages"

A more detailed description can be found at the top of the link. I hope nobody needs to try, but if, I hope it helps.