# Failed installation of Windows Service Pack 1 ( Error 800B0100)

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I've searched for solutions (such as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/450250/windows-7-service-pack-1-error)) but I am unable to find any solution to my issue.

I did a complete fresh install of Windows 7 Home Edition yesterday and I actually had installed SP1 earlier today. Later, there was an unrelated issue and I decided to do a system restore. **Since the System Restore, I cannot install Service Pack 1**. I tried running the Windows Update Troubleshooter and the System Update Readiness tool several times but I still can't install SP1. The error code is always 800B0100

**UPDATE:** I attempted to manually install the update obtained from Microsoft ([here)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/15090/windows-7-install-service-pack-1-sp1) but I got this error message:

[image]

This doesn't make sense as I am definitely running Windows 7 Home Edition 64bit.

Comment: Update manually? https://superuser.com/questions/320100/windows-7-update-failure-800b0100

Comment: I had to do it from an old CD. The laptop was basically unusable until I put in the installation CD and did a clean install

Comment: WSUS? You mean windows update right? I’ve run it over 10 times now and still it fails to install service pack 1

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Windows update is downloading the package just fine but it is the installation that is failing

Comment: IA64.exe is the wrong file . That ‘s for an Itanium server

Comment: I forgot to provide the entire program name, WSUS Offline, so I wasn’t talking about Windows Update.  WSUS isn’t technically Windows Update though

Comment: Still IA64 is probably the wrong file as the error message indicates. It must be  not the  IA file used

Answer (score 0):

I got the Service Pack installed by a manual installation:

Go here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842 and select the correct version for your OS.